# ios ScrollView empty blank area does not scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have created a scrollview programmatically in ios.

I am displaying 2-3 images on that scrollview and adding images vertically one below other.
When I touch on the image and scroll vertically it works. But if I touch the empty space between the images and try to scroll it does not work. Scrollview does not respond to that.

Here is the relevant code :

```
        UIImageView* imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:imageRect];
        [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];
        [scrollView addSubview:imageView];
        [self didAddSubview:imageView];
        .....
        ...... 
        [scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
        [[self view] addSubview:scrollView];
```

Any inputs will be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using any custom gesture recognizers?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the content size of scrollView use this code hope it will help you :-

```
 - (void) viewDidLoad
{
     [super viewDidLoad];

     UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568)];

        [scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];

        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 250, 200)];

        [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];

        [scrollView addSubview:imageView];


        [self.view addSubview:scrollView];

        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 600);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set,

```
[scrollView setFrame:size];
[scrollView setContentSize:contentsize];
```

If it will not scroll **vertically** or **horizontally** then you have to change content size it should be greater then current size.

Answer (score 0):

This question is old but I was having the exact same issue with my scrollview, and this was the only page I found about this all over the internet.
I was using a content view inside scroll view, and I just set a background color on my contentView and it worked.
Content size was being set automatically throw auto layout, so no need to set it manually.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).